# Laravel API Resource get Collection Columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In a *Resource* Object, can I somehow loop through the columns that are part of the query?

**$this** seems to be from type *Query\Builder*. 
**$this->resource** is a reference to the *Eloquent\Model*.

As I sent the *Eloquent/Collection* as parameter to the Resource, is it available somewhere ?

I know about the function *$this->toArray()* but I wonder if there is something more robust like *$this->getColumns()*

Comment: try [this](https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/get-table-column-names-as-array-from-eloquent-model)

Comment: got it working with $this->resource->getAttributes()